# Concrete5 Tooltip Loading Twice

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, concrete5

I have a tooltip link in the footer of my client's test site (the About Northwoods Link), http://www.nwlodge.vemglobal.net/... . The tooltip block shows up for guests, but not to users or admins who are logged into Concrete5. I thought it was a because JQuery UI was loading twice, but I removed the script calling the JQuery UI file from the theme header.

The tooltip div contains a Concrete5 block that needs to be editable in Concrete5.

Here is the javascript that I load for the tooltip (and a supersized background)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
     jQuery("#more").tooltip({ 
     effect: 'fade', 
     direction: 'up',
     position: "top left",
     delay: 1000, 
     offset: [-13, 165], 
     relative: true,
     tip: '.morebox'
});         

$.supersized({
     slide_interval          :   2500, 
     transition              :   1,    
     transition_speed      :   1500,     
     slides               :   [     
     { image : '/themes/nwlodge/images/slideshow-img-1.jpg' },
     { image : '/themes/nwlodge/images/slideshow-img-2.jpg' },
     { image : '/themes/nwlodge/images/slideshow-img-3.jpg' }                                      
                         ]               
  });
});
```

The code for the Tooltip link (when logged into C5) is as follows:

```
 <a id="more" class="up-arrow" href="#" data-original-title="">About Northwoods Lodge</a>
```

Comment: Any JS errors when logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you didn't do something funky with permissions in the dashboard.
Recently I noticed something weird with that.

Say for a specific file I want to override fileset/file manager permissions. I do that and for viewing I have administrators and guests allowed. Instantly the file doesn't show up for guests.

I assume it's a C5 bug. Maybe you have the same situation.